# How exactly does GitHub squash and merge?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have two branches:

- `master`
- `feature-1`

And I want to squash and merge feature-1 into master.  I have a pull request open to do this.

**What git command is GitHub doing when I click the green Squash and Merge button on my pull request?**

Is it:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-1 --squash --no-edit
```

...or something else?

For example, if I wanted to be able to predict what the result of the squash and merge would be, or predict whether or not there would be a merge conflict, I'd like to try it locally first.  But what git command would I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub does not use any of Git's built in operations directly here, but it does get the *equivalent* of what you suggested.  The key differences between the green button labeled "squash and merge" and doing `git merge --squash` is that if `git merge --squash` *succeeds*, it does not make a *commit* yet, and if it *fails*, it leaves the partial merge in your index and work-tree.  The GitHub button does nothing if the squash would have failed, and makes a commit if the squash would have succeeded.